# How do you trigger rendering template when data is arrive though resolve in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I can call for first time load in controller like this

```
function RankCtrl($scope, $route, $routeParams, Rank) {
   $scope.leagues = Rank.query($routeParams)
}
```

When route changes, I am using resolve to load data from server.
(and changing route is just an json request to server, so nothing will be refreshed in page.)

```
app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/rank/:type/:top', {
    controller: "RankCtrl",
    resolve: {
      leagues: function($route, $q, Rank) {
        return Rank.query($route.current.params)
      }
    }
  })

  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

I can see data is properly retrieve from server though chrome dev tools.

But where did the data go? I like to assign that data to $scope.leagues, and want to update the view (template) based on new data.

I also tried to used `$scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess')` event but that globally trigger all the route changes not only limit to this controller.

```
$scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(next, current) { 
  $scope.leagues = Rank.query($routeParams);
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: At first glance, your `resolve` doesn't seem to be returning anything.

Comment: I just tried to add return Rank.query( .....) , still same, @dcodesmith

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to inject the `RankCtrl` with the name of the resolve property (`leagues`);

```
function RankCtrl($scope, $route, $routeParams, leagues) {
   $scope.leagues = leagues;
}
```

Update:

Depending on Angular version you might need to manually construct and resolve the promise object:

```
/* ... */
resolve: {
  leagues: function($route, $q, Rank) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    return Rank.query($route.current.params, function(leagues){
      deferred.resolve(leagues);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there any other thing to change? I got `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: leaguesProvider <- leagues`

Comment: Any chance you're using `RankCtrl` with `ng-controller` directive anywhere in your views?

Comment: I have `<div ng-controller="RankCtrl">`, need to change it?

Comment: Definitely. When using $routeProvider to assign controller to a view and to a route, you don't need and can't use `ng-controller` directive with the same controller.

Comment: I am using 1.2.6 from googlecdn. I changed the resolve code to the one you provided. what do I do need to change for `<div ng-controller="RankCtrl">`, just `<div>`?

Comment: Yes, remove `ng-controller="RankCtrl"` part.

Comment: Removed, but now it does not seems to load data from server anymore, also not rendering anything. but no error on console.

Comment: OK, time for a plunker. Once you set it up I can assist you in SO chat.

Comment: btw, the ng-controller **directive** you mean is something I made with `.directive`? I dont have any directive created that way. I only have .factory, .config, .controller. EDIT: how do u setup server side on plunder btw?

Comment: nvm, I solved the problem (kind of) by attaching $scope variable to the function itself, and referencing it from resolve function.